# Ubuntu+Apache2 - Not allowing outside connection?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I've got a box running Ubuntu 10.04, and I have Apache2 installed. When I'm on the box I can go to http://localhost/ and it connects to the web server fine. I can also go directly to my IP and connect no problem. However, if I try to connect from another computer on the network, either through the DNS or direct IP, my connection times out.

However, I can connect to the box via SSH just fine, as well as ping the box.

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE:

When running nmap on the local computer I get the following:

```
wayne@media-box:~$ sudo nmap -sS -O -PI -PT 192.168.1.70

Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-06-28 06:32 CDT
Interesting ports on media-box (192.168.1.70):
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
25/tcp  open  smtp
80/tcp  open  http
143/tcp open  imap
993/tcp open  imaps
```

However, if I run it from another box on the network:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-06-28 06:32 CDT
Interesting ports on media-box (192.168.1.70):
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
113/tcp closed auth
```

So 80 is open to the box itself but not the outside world? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any other firewalls installed?

- Yes, shorewall

Well

```
# sudo apt-get remove shorewall
```

and that will fix it.

Comment: Removing the firewall is not a solution :/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that something enabled Ubuntu's built-in (but usually disabled by default) firewall, ufw. Try running:

```
$ ufw status
```

If ufw is enabled, and you want to disable it, run `ufw disable`. If you want to leave the firewall enabled and whitelist HTTP traffic, run `ufw allow Apache`

Comment: It's disabled :-\

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely could be a firewall problem, but I couldn't tell you what might be wrong without seeing your firewall rules. You can run

```
iptables -L
```

to list them, and paste the output into your question if you need help interpreting it.

I've written an [IPTables tutorial/reference](http://www.ellipsix.net/geninfo/firewall/index.html) (link is to my website) that might be useful. Part of it is a short guide to configuring the firewall on a Linux server, i.e. what commands to run, what rules to add, and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing this box from local network, are you using the private or the public IP of the box?

When accessing from local network you should use one of the 192.168.XXX.XXX, 10.XXX.XXX.XXX or 172.16.XXX.XXX prefixes...

Comment: 192.168.XXX.XXXX - it's the same IP I can successfully ping and ssh to, but for some reason port 80 is not connecting

Comment: if you're using iptables, post here the output of iptables -L -v please